# Kubernetes worker node external ip how to get it

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

How to get external IP address of worker node using Kubernetes API in Java.
I am able to get internal IP of worker node, but external IP I am not able to access it.
Please let me know how can I get external IP

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: I tried using below api calls  
V1PodList list = api.listNamespacedPod(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); 
V1ServiceList listNamespacedService = api.listNamespacedService(null, null, null, null, null, null,
    null, null, null, null);

Comment: But I didnt get external ip from these api's output

Answer (score 0):

> > Not Sure about the kubernetes api in java. But " kubectl get nodes -o wide  " shows both internal & external IPs of that node.

Comment: yes using this command we can see it.But I have one requirement to get external ip of worker node in which pod is running.